# Domain-specific data science programs

Tags: data, education

I am looking for domain-specific data science programs (as a major, not a minor or specialization). I found programs in bio-statistics (and other disciplines in public health), MS in marketing analytics, MS in learning analytics and MS in urban informatics. Does anyone know any other domain-specific data science field of study?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsurprisingly most programs in data science focus mostly on business or marketing applications. I too would like to see more programs focused on Biotechnology, Gaming or Energy for example but I think that in the future those kind of programs will become more and more available.
However there are a few I know of that offer a somewhat different approach.

Regarding health informatics there are many offers where you can find anything between Public health to Computational Biology and Quantitative Genetics. Take a look at the full list.

http://www.mastersindatascience.org/specialties/health-informatics/

On that list there are a few certification programs but there also are full fledged programs that lead to a M.Sc.

If you are more interested in Marketing Analytics you can find the same list but for marketing related programs.

http://www.mastersindatascience.org/specialties/marketing-analytics/

other options like Information Systems are also present, just browse that site and you might find something that interests you.

Comment: Thank you. I added Computational Biology and Quantitative Genetics to my list. Your post also reminded me of computational social science.

Answer (score 2):

I found a PhD in Energy Informatics at [Karlsruhe Institute of Technology (KIT)](http://www.energystatusdata.kit.edu/index.php) and PhD in Learning Analytics at [University of Technology Sydney](http://utscic.edu.au/research/phd/)

Comment: Interesting!  Can you include more details in the answer :)

Comment: I have no more information except the link.